# Anorm Pattern Matching and deprecated list method

Tags: json, scala, anorm

I'm using PlayFramework with Anorm to build a REST service with JSON data.

Since I don't know all the database columns in advance, then I've used pattern matching for mapping Row into JSON object.

I've used the example from the documentation ([Using-Pattern-Matching](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.2/ScalaAnorm#Using-Pattern-Matching)) as a starting point.

```
def any2jsValue(v: Any): JsValue = v match {
    case v2: String => JsString(v2)
    case v2: Long => JsNumber(v2)
    case v2: Int => JsNumber(v2)
    case v2: Double => JsNumber(v2)
    case v2: Float => JsNumber(v2)
    case v2: Some[Any] => any2jsValue(v2.get)
    case None => JsNull
    case v2: Any => JsString("MAPPING NOT IMPLEMENTED: " + v2.getClass()     + "  Value: " + v2.toString)
  }

def row2jsObject(row: Row): JsObject = row.asMap.map({
  case (k: String, v: Any) => Json.obj(k -> any2jsValue(v))
}).foldLeft(Json.obj())((r: JsObject, c: JsObject) => r ++ Json.obj(c.keys.head -> c.values.head))

val sql = SQL("SELECT * FROM world.City WHERE name = 'Milano'")

val cities = sql.map({
  case row: Row => row2jsObject(row)
}).list

Json.obj("cities" -> cities)
```

The code works fine, but the compiler is warning me that:

> method list in class SimpleSql is deprecated: Use `SQL("...").as(parser.*)`

How to do the same work without the deprecated list method?

I've tried both to implement a parser, and to search alternative methods in the API, but without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not to use the deprecated `.list`, a `RowParser` must be defined and used with `.*` combinator; e.g:

```scala
import java.sql.Connection
import anorm._

trait Country
case class SmallCountry(name:String) extends Country
case class BigCountry(name:String) extends Country
case object France extends Country

val patternParser = RowParser[Country] {
  case Row("France", _) => Success(France)
  case Row(name:String, pop:Int) if (pop > 1000000) => Success(BigCountry(name))
  case Row(name:String, _) => Success(SmallCountry(name))
  case row => Error(TypeDoesNotMatch(s"unexpected: $row"))
}

def countries(implicit con: Connection): List[Country] =
  SQL("SELECT name,population FROM Country WHERE id = {i}").
    on("i" -> "id").as(patternParser.*)
```

In your case:

```scala
import anorm.{ RowParser, SqlResult, Success }

def row2jsObject(row: Row): SqlResult[JsObject] = Success(row.asMap.map({
  case (k: String, v: Any) => Json.obj(k -> any2jsValue(v))
}).foldLeft(Json.obj())((r: JsObject, c: JsObject) => r ++ Json.obj(c.keys.head -> c.values.head)))

val parser: RowParser[JsObject] = RowParser(row2jsObject(_))
val cities: List[JsObject] =
  SQL("SELECT * FROM world.City WHERE name = 'Milano'").as(parser.*)
```